# UICollectionView is not scrolling smoothly

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm using `UICollectionView` in my app for displaying images. Its working but the problem the scrolling is not smooth. I have created GridView using multiple ImageViews in `UITableView` for another app(below iOS 6). That does not have this problem scrolling works very smoothly. Why this happening for `UICollectionView` ??

```
- (PSUICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(PSUICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

RSCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_images objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image = image;
    });
});


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps could you post the code you are using...

Comment: @Zaphod i posted code

Comment: How large are the images? I have performance problems with images 200x200 pixel PNGs on a iPhone 4, but it's smooth on iPhone 4s or above.

Comment: I'm not sure using queue will help you on efficiency. Have you just tried: `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_images objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];` ?